# 12:41 puzzle: colorful geometry

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, computer-puzzle

[image: 12:41]
The answer is a 4-letter word. I will not be giving any hints.
This puzzle is very old. The puzzle is solved using only the image (no clues to the puzzle in title or description).

Comment: Did you make this puzzle yourself?

Comment: Yes, a long time ago. Probably last year iirc. I don't remember exactly how you solve it but I still remember the answer.

Comment: My color picker says some solid colors have slightly different color values within them, probably because it's a jpeg. In case the exact color values are important, please upload a png version. To prevent i.stack.imgur from converting a png to a jpg, the image must be less than 1MB large (which shouldn't be a problem at all for such an image)

Comment: Thanks for informing me about this. I have changed the image to a png, but this does not necessarily mean that the puzzle involves specific color values.

Comment: The new image is the exact same file as the old one.

Comment: Wha... I changed the file format though???

Comment: Will give rgb values in another post when i have time.

Comment: might as well spill the beans, specific color values dont matter that much